# Two extensions and one menu item

Tags: visual-studio, vs-extensibility

I want to use two VS extensions. Each extension creates its own menu item in VS2012 main menu. I would like to merge these menu items to one menu item. Is it possible to change vsix files to obtain this behavior or I should change the source code?

Comment: Why? What is the motivation for doing this? Why have two extensions with a single menu item? If they can share a menu item, why do they need to be two separate extensions?

Comment: For some logical reason. The first extension is MonoHelper which run xbuild instead msbuild, and the second one is MonoRemoteDebuger which run debug  on remote device. I would prefer to have these options into one single menu (say Mono) instead of two different.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm very interested into this topic

Comment: No, I have not found good solution. I tried to merge sources of these extensions into single one, but finally just get rid of one extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify Visual Studio menu using Tools - Customize - Commands tab:

[image]